# Finding Unique Values from two or more tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, unique, distinct

I have two tables, `training_taken_november` and `qtr1_copy`. Each of them have a unique field. I want to join these two tables and count the unique values from both tables where their `category = 'livestock'`, illustration below:

```
Tbl1 values might be: 1,2,3,4,5

Tbl2 values might be: 6,7,8,1,2
```

The count of distinct values should return: 8, that is, when we join the two tables they have 8 unique values in mentioned fields (name of fields that have unique values also differ).

[image]

Comment: please show your table structure

Comment: I have edited the Question, so please follow the link for image.

Comment: Add table sample data, not just for one column, and show us the expected result with that data. Join how? You say both tables where their category = 'livestock', but only one of the tables have that column...

Answer (score 0):

```
Select count(*) from
(
Select id from ... Where category...
Union
Select id from ... Where cat ...
) x
```

Comment: So your query gives 982, but the actual unique from both tables is 1157(i manually took the date from both tables, then i moved it to Excel and removed duplicates and found this value). so still no query to find that out

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
Select count(*) from
(select tazkira from Training_taken_november where category='Livestock'
union
select bene from qtr1_copy where cat='Livestock')x
```